# discord.py mute everyone in voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

this is my code rn:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('BOT ACTIVATED')
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hei this is a test just dont mind me")
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()


client.run('mytoken')
```

how do i mute everyone in that voice channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through all members of the voice channel and pass `mute=True` to the [`edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit) function.

```
@client.command()
async def vcmute(ctx):
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    for member in vc.members:
        await member.edit(mute=True)
```